# My test runner file is not running, but not showing any errors

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Below  is my test runner file, When I run, its not executing, not even showing any errors.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:features"},
        glue = {"com.xx.xx.xx.automation.stepdefs"},
        tags = {"@SanityTest"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber.html","junit:target/cucumber.xml"},
        monochrome = true,
        dryRun = false, strict=true)

public class Srt3AppRunner {

}
```

/********* below is my Feature file, I have added tags, but still runner file doesn't run - ***************************************/
@SanityTest
Feature: To check the functionality for adding a new Key-list values and to check if able to add same key-list values,
verifying the title and add new key for range of values, also to verify the buttons on Add New Key popup

Background: User clicks on Add New Key button on profile dashboard page
Given user logs in through "Guardian page"
When user is on profile dashboard page "Global Profile Module"
Then click on "Add New Key" button

@SanityTest
Scenario: Click on Add New Key popup to see Add new key, Key description, Checkbox, Add value to key fields and Value type dropdown, Save, Cancel buttons
And can see "Add new key", "Key description", "Add value to key" fields, "Select a value type" dropdown, and Checkbox "This key has no default value"
And can see "Add Value" plus button, "Save", "Cancel" buttons

Please help me with this, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the project structure/setup.

However, I would advise checking that the glue path is correct, e.g "src/test/stepDefinitions" and that a tag matching @SanityTest has actually been added to one of your feature files/scenarios

Comment: My project structure - 


src/main/java

                     - com.xx.xx.xx.automation.stepdefs
                     - com.xx.xx.xx.automation.runners


src/main/resources


                     - features


and yes @SatinyTest is added in my feature files/scenarios